# Visual Studio key strokes to move between panes of a split view

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

Using Visual Studio to edit a file I can’t find a key stroke to move between panes of a split view.

Moving between windows is easy enough with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, but no keystrokes to move between panes of a split view.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203844/what-is-the-hotkey-to-jump-between-split-windows-in-visual-studio-2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [What is the hotkey to jump between split windows in Visual Studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203844/what-is-the-hotkey-to-jump-between-split-windows-in-visual-studio-2008)

F6 for next split pane or Shift+F6 for previous split pane.

The keyboard mapping has to be set to Default and not Visual C# 2005 under

Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard

Setting to default removes the Build function for F6, alternatively reassign to another key sequence.